# how to make a filter with radio button and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to filter a list of clients based on radio buttons and also based on checkboxes how can I make them work together? basically I need to be able to see the following combinations

```
ALL
ALL-NATIONALS
ALL-FOREIGN
PROD
PROD-NATIONAL 
PROD-FOREIGN 
TEST
TESTS-NATIONAL 
TESTS-FOREIGN
```

I tried these two ways but it doesn't work

```js
//test 1

$(function() {
  var dom = $('#elenco .cliente');
  $('input[name="test"]').on('change', function(a, b) {
    value1 = this.value;
    console.log(value1)
    $('#elenco .cliente').hide();
    if (value1 == 'All') {
      $('#elenco .cliente').show();
      dom = $('#elenco .cliente');
      $('#sito').val('')
      $('#IP').val('')
    }
    if (value1 == 'PROD') {
      $('#elenco .cliente[value="PROD"]').show();
      dom = $('#elenco .cliente[value="PROD"]');
    }
    if (value1 == 'TEST') {
      $('#elenco .cliente[value="TEST"]').show();
      dom = $('#elenco .cliente[value="TEST"]');
    }
    if ($('#check-naz').is(':checked')) {
      $('.naz').show();
      dom = $('.naz');
    }
    if ($('#check-est').is(':checked')) {
      $('.estero').show();
      dom = $('.estero');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sito" class="find" name="txt" placeholder="CLIENTE" type="text" size=15>
<input id="IP" class="find" name="txt" placeholder="INDIRIZZO IP" type="text" size=15>
<input id='all' class="filter" type="radio" value="All" checked name="test"><label>All</label>
<input id='prod' class="filter" type="radio" value="PROD" name="test"><label>PROD</label>
<input id='test' class="filter" type="radio" value="TEST" name="test"><label>TEST</label>
<input id="check-naz" type="checkbox" class="filter check" value="NAZ" name="test"><label>NAZIONALI</label>
<input id="check-est" type="checkbox" class="filter check" value="EST" name="test"><label>ESTERI</label>
<div id="elenco">
  <div class="cliente naz" value="PROD">
    cliente
    <div class="desc">
      scommettendo prod <br>


    </div>
    <div class="funzioni">
      <span>
                             <span>INDIRIZZI IP</span>
      </span>
      <button type="button" onclick="managerScomP(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('manager'))" id="m1">manager</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="reloadmemScommP(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload'), 'resultScommP')" id="r1">reload</button>
      <br>

      <ul>
        <li class="version"><button type="button" onclick="UpVersioneT(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('versione')+'/upgradeVersion','upVersionScommP')" class="rs1">UpVersione</button>
          <div class="resultVersion" id="upVersionScommP">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="rilascio(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('versione')+'/upgradeVersion?isRelease=1 ','rilascio-scommettendo-P')" class="rs1 rilascio">Rilascio</button>
          <div class="resultVersion" id="rilascio-scommettendo-P">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[0]+'/XPayments/reload','resultScommP0')" class="rs1">10.38.0.21</button>
          <div class="result" id="resultScommP0">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[1]+'/XPayments/reload','resultScommP1')" class="rs1"></button>
          <div class="result" id="resultScommP1">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[2]+'/XPayments/reload','resultScommP2')" class="rs1"></button>
          <div class="result" id="resultScommP2">Risultato</div>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cliente estero" value="PROD">
    cliente
    <div class="desc">
      betafrik prod <br>


    </div>
    <div class="funzioni">
      <span>INDIRIZZI IP</span>
      <button type="button" onclick="managerScomP(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('manager'))" id="m1">manager</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="reloadmemScommP(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('reload'),'resultBetafrikP')" id="r1">reload</button>
      <br>
      <ul>
        <li class="version"><button type="button" onclick="UpVersioneT(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('versione') + '/upgradeVersion','UpVersioneBetafrikP')" class="rs1">UpVersione</button>
          <div class="resultVersion" id="UpVersioneBetafrikP">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="rilascio(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('versione')+'/upgradeVersion?isRelease=1 ','rilascio-betafrik-P')" class="rs1 rilascio">Rilascio</button>
          <div class="resultVersion" id="rilascio-betafrik-P">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('reload')[0] +'/XPayments/reload','resultBetafrikP0')" class="rs1"></button>
          <div class="result" id="resultBetafr
    
    ikP0">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('reload')[1] +'/XPayments/reload','resultBetafrikP1')" class="rs1"></button>
          <div class="result" id="resultBetafrikP1">Risultato</div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
// test 2

$(function() {
  var dom = $('#elenco .cliente');
  $('input[name="test"]').on('change', function(a, b) {
    value1 = this.value;
    console.log(value1)
    $('#elenco .cliente').hide();
    if (value1 == 'All') {
      $('#elenco .cliente').show();
      dom = $('#elenco .cliente');
      $('#sito').val('')
      $('#IP').val('')
    }
    if (value1 == 'PROD') {
      $('#elenco .cliente[value="PROD"]').show();
      dom = $('#elenco .cliente[value="PROD"]');
    }
    if (value1 == 'TEST') {
      $('#elenco .cliente[value="TEST"]').show();
      dom = $('#elenco .cliente[value="TEST"]');
    }
    if (value1 == 'NAZ') {
      $('.naz').show();
      dom = $('.naz');
    }
    if (value1 == 'EST') {
      $('.estero').show();
      dom = $('.estero');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sito" class="find" name="txt" placeholder="CLIENTE" type="text" size=15>
<input id="IP" class="find" name="txt" placeholder="INDIRIZZO IP" type="text" size=15>
<input id='all' class="filter" type="radio" value="All" checked name="test"><label>All</label>
<input id='prod' class="filter" type="radio" value="PROD" name="test"><label>PROD</label>
<input id='test' class="filter" type="radio" value="TEST" name="test"><label>TEST</label>
<input id="check-naz" type="checkbox" class="filter check" value="NAZ" name="test"><label>NAZIONALI</label>
<input id="check-est" type="checkbox" class="filter check" value="EST" name="test"><label>ESTERI</label>
<div id="elenco">
  <div class="cliente naz" value="PROD">
    cliente
    <div class="desc">
      scommettendo prod <br>


    </div>
    <div class="funzioni">
      <span>
                             <span>INDIRIZZI IP</span>
      </span>
      <button type="button" onclick="managerScomP(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('manager'))" id="m1">manager</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="reloadmemScommP(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload'), 'resultScommP')" id="r1">reload</button>
      <br>

      <ul>
        <li class="version"><button type="button" onclick="UpVersioneT(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('versione')+'/upgradeVersion','upVersionScommP')" class="rs1">UpVersione</button>
          <div class="resultVersion" id="upVersionScommP">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="rilascio(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('versione')+'/upgradeVersion?isRelease=1 ','rilascio-scommettendo-P')" class="rs1 rilascio">Rilascio</button>
          <div class="resultVersion" id="rilascio-scommettendo-P">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[0]+'/XPayments/reload','resultScommP0')" class="rs1">10.38.0.21</button>
          <div class="result" id="resultScommP0">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[1]+'/XPayments/reload','resultScommP1')" class="rs1"></button>
          <div class="result" id="resultScommP1">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('scommettendo').get('scommettendo prod').get('reload')[2]+'/XPayments/reload','resultScommP2')" class="rs1"></button>
          <div class="result" id="resultScommP2">Risultato</div>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cliente estero" value="PROD">
    cliente
    <div class="desc">
      betafrik prod <br>


    </div>
    <div class="funzioni">
      <span>INDIRIZZI IP</span>
      <button type="button" onclick="managerScomP(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('manager'))" id="m1">manager</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="reloadmemScommP(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('reload'),'resultBetafrikP')" id="r1">reload</button>
      <br>
      <ul>
        <li class="version"><button type="button" onclick="UpVersioneT(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('versione') + '/upgradeVersion','UpVersioneBetafrikP')" class="rs1">UpVersione</button>
          <div class="resultVersion" id="UpVersioneBetafrikP">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="rilascio(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('versione')+'/upgradeVersion?isRelease=1 ','rilascio-betafrik-P')" class="rs1 rilascio">Rilascio</button>
          <div class="resultVersion" id="rilascio-betafrik-P">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('reload')[0] +'/XPayments/reload','resultBetafrikP0')" class="rs1"></button>
          <div class="result" id="resultBetafr
    
    ikP0">Risultato</div>
        </li>
        <li><button type="button" onclick="reloadmem(clienti.get('betafrik').get('betafrik prod').get('reload')[1] +'/XPayments/reload','resultBetafrikP1')" class="rs1"></button>
          <div class="result" id="resultBetafrikP1">Risultato</div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please post a ***[mcve]*** of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. I created the snippets for you, now tell us what they did not do that you expected them to do

Comment: when the checkboxes are returned to unchecked the list of items shown does not change

Comment: when the checkboxes are not selected you must obviously see everything based on the selected radio button

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13iBZKKWVgxSgiYykcxV9NFPbbNApSOPs

this drive contains the files containing the entire code